# Oledb Insert statement using parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

How do I insert into parameters from different tables using OleDB?

I have 3 tables:
1. itemTbl
2. crateTbl
3. contentTbl

itemTbl has: itemID, itemName, itemDesc
crateTbl has: crateID, crateName
contentTbl has: crateID, itemID, qty

contentTbl is the contents of the crate and the qty of each

I need it to select values in different tables I use `WHERE`. I have tried a similar code using a local db and service based db and they allow me, but OleDB doesn't let me use VALUES((SELECT))....

Error message:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Query input must contain at least one table or query.

My code:

```
cmd.Dispose();

cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO contentTbl(crateID,itemID,qty) VALUES((SELECT crateTbl.crateID FROM crateTbl WHERE crateTbl.crateID=?),(SELECT itemTbl.itemID FROM itemTbl WHERE itemTbl.itemID = ?), ?)";
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("crateID", txtCrate.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("itemID", txtItem.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("qty", txtQty.Text));

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Done!");

da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM contentTbl", con);
da.Fill(dt);

dgvContent.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: The first thing I've noticed is that you have an extra comma at the end of your columns list. The second thing is that `OLEDB doesn't let me use VALUES((SELECT))` doesn't really tell us much. Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? What database are you working with?

Comment: I was editing that one xD sorry. I'm using an access database.

It says:
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Query input must contain at least one table or query.'

Comment: It's been forever since I've last worked with ms-access. Are you sure that syntax is valid? Did you try hard-coding values into the parameter placeholders and run it directly in access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite descriptive. Access doesn't support subqueries without a main query, so change the syntax round to use one of the subqueries as your main query:

```
INSERT INTO  contentTbl(crateID,itemID,qty)
SELECT crateTbl.crateID,(SELECT itemTbl.itemID FROM itemTbl WHERE itemTbl.itemID = ?), ?
FROM crateTbl WHERE crateTbl.crateID=?
```

Note that parameters are passed by position, and rewriting this query does require you to re-order parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("itemID", txtItem.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("qty", txtQty.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("crateID", txtCrate.Text));
```

If you don't like the main query/subquery syntax, you can go for a cross join too:

```
INSERT INTO  contentTbl(crateID,itemID,qty)
SELECT crateTbl.crateID, itemTbl.itemID, ?
FROM crateTbl,itemTbl  
WHERE crateTbl.crateID=? AND itemTbl.itemID = ?
```

(Parameter order needs to be adjusted again but you can figure that out).

Comment: I'll try this out xD it looks like a weird sandwich... Thank you so much! It works now! :D

Comment: I've added an alternate syntax if you don't like the current one :)

Comment: Wait! It will insert now but crateID and itemID are switched =__=

Comment: I said you needed to adjust the parameter order... Are you using the first or the second solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the syntax. I always use it like (this is from VB, but C# should be similar) :

cmd.Parameters.Addwithvalue("crateID", txtCrate.Text)

Comment: This is how I did my local db codes but it doesn't work in access :/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it sort of works, but for some reason works only with values for the items table as ID's. If I have an ID (they're ints) that crateTbl has but itemTbl doesn't, it doesn't insert.

```
cmd.Dispose();
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO contentTbl(itemID,crateID,qty) SELECT itemTbl.itemID,(SELECT crateTbl.crateID FROM crateTbl WHERE crateTbl.crateID = ?), ? FROM itemTbl WHERE itemTbl.itemID=?";

cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("itemID", txtItem.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("qty", txtQty.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("crateID", txtCrate.Text));

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Done!");

dt2.Clear();
```