# C# DBHandlerSystem.Data.OleDb.OleDbException error

Tags: c#, ms-access

so I'm trying to connect a window form to my access database.

This is my code that inputs data from my form

```
 private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
            string myQuery = "INSERT INTO question(Question1) VALUES ( "+Question.Text+" )";
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Question Saved");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception in DBHandler" + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

I'm getting this error

```
Exception in DBHandlerSystem.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): No value given for one or more required parameters. at System.Data.01eDb.0IeDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandlin g(OleDbHResult hr) at System.Data.01eDb.0IeDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleRes ult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) at System.Data.01eDb.0IeDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavi or behavior, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.01eDb.01eDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(Commande ehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.01eDb.01eDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuety0 at ADOExample.Forml.buttonSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Misers Wser\Desktop1Assigment\ LEVEL 5\AWD\ code for lab 07\ code for lab OTADOExample\ADOExample Vorml.csaine 37
```

I don't know if there is a typo or something.

Any help would be appreciated.

I know that someone else has posted about the same issue but it not working for my system.

Comment: The following may be helpfu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687434/oledb-insert-statement-using-parameters